# How to allow admin users to masquerade as regular users who have not confirmed their email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I am using Devise in a Ruby on Rails application.  I have two types of users in my system, "Admin" and "User".  In my application I allow admin users to "masquerade" or impersonate a User by logging in as them.

```
class Admin::Users::MasqueradeController < Admin::BaseController
  load_and_authorize_resource :user, only: :create

  def create
      sign_in(:user, @user)
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end
end
```

This works great however if the user has not confirmed their email, devise will immediately throw an error in the "sign_in" method and returns the default "You have to confirm your email address before continuing.".  I need to find a way to skip this check when a "current_admin_user" exists.

My current solution is to set allow_unconfirmed_access_for to nil however this turns the check off for all users.  Instead, I'd like it to only skip the check when an admin is currently logged in.  So, I ended up having to recreate this check at the SessionsController level and simply make sure it doesn't fire for admins. This feels dirty and it's not an ideal solution.

```
config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = nil
```

Really appreciate any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work, but you could try to set the confirmed_at on the `@user`.

```
class Admin::Users::MasqueradeController < Admin::BaseController
  load_and_authorize_resource :user, only: :create

  def create
      @user.confirmed_at = DateTime.now
      sign_in(:user, @user)
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end
end
```

Or actually update it for a second:

```
class Admin::Users::MasqueradeController < Admin::BaseController
  load_and_authorize_resource :user, only: :create

  def create
      @user.update(confirmed_at: DateTime.now)
      sign_in(:user, @user)
      @user.update(confirmed_at: nil)
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end
end
```

Comment: This would work for the initial sign_in however the confirmed_at is actually checked a bunch of times.  So as soon as you hit the next page it will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

## user.rb

```
def confirmed?
  admin_user?
end
```

function admin_user? must return true for you'r admin user.

Comment: Don't believe this works. The admin user isn't the one being checked when the admin is logging into the other account.  Admin A masquerades as User B and it's User B that is being checked for whether they have confirmed their account.

Comment: what is the process of masqureradind as user B, switching user while keeping some cookie identifying admin user?